# How to join multiple tables in MySQL 2?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I want to see a citizen's full name

where notifyEmployee ='1' in reportBasket,reportNoBasket tables

AND reportNoBasket.groupEmail IS NOT NULL

AND count email from reportBasket, citizenEmail reportNOBasket in one counter

Tables:

> citizen(**email**, firstname,lastname)
>
> reportBasket(**email**,notifyEmployee)
>
> reportNoBasket(**citizenEmail**, notifyEmployee , groupEmail)

**BEFORE** I was represent my Query to show their email in this way, it was working Good :

```
SELECT email,count(email) as email_count 
FROM (
    SELECT email
    FROM reportBasket
    WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT citizenEmail
    FROM reportNoBasket
    WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
) as T
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY email ASC
```

**BUT NOW I want to show the citizen's full name instead of the email address**  e.g. `concat(citizen.firstname,' ' citizen.lastname)`

How can I join it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname), count(*) as citizen_count 
FROM (
    SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname
    FROM reportBasket rb
    JOIN citizen c
        ON rb.email = c.email
    WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname
    FROM reportNoBasket rnb
    JOIN citizen c
        ON rnb.citizenEmail = c.email
    WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
) as T
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
ORDER BY firstname, lastname ASC
```

Comment: Just add it in all 3 `SELECT` statements, and the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to group items still by emails (as they are unique) and then just join citizen table to add name

```
SELECT email,count(email) as email_count, concat(citizen.firstname,' ' citizen.lastname)
FROM ( SELECT email
       FROM reportBasket
       WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT citizenEmail
       FROM reportNoBasket
       WHERE notifyEmployee='1')as T
LEFT JOIN citizen USING (email)
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY email ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT count(email) as email_count, concat(citizen.firstname,' ' citizen.lastname) as name
FROM ( SELECT email
       FROM reportBasket
       WHERE notifyEmployee='1'
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT citizenEmail
       FROM reportNoBasket
       WHERE notifyEmployee='1')as T
LEFT JOIN citizen USING (email)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC
```